# What happens when there is duplicate path param?

Tags: java, web, jax-rs

Imagining that I have some endpoint defined as:

```
@Path("path/{variable}/{variable}")
class Resource {
    @Path("hey")
    public void function(@PathParam("variable") final String variable) {

    }
}
```

In the case of calling `path/A/B/hey` what will be the value bound to `variable`?

I'm aware I could use `UriInfo#getPathParameters()` but I'd like to know what's the specified behaviour in this case.

**EDIT:** this was obviously a simplification of the problem, the real issue here is when I'm trying to have several resources to inherit from a common behaviour.

Example: imagine that I have nested resources for a family tree (son, father, grandfather) and I want to be able to get the children of a given type.

I'd write:

```
class AbstractFamilyMember {
    @Path("children")
    public Collection<Stuff> children(@PathParam("name") final String name) {
        return (...);
    }
}

@Path(URL)
class Grandfather extends AbstractFamilyMember {
    public static final String URL = "something/{name}";
}

@Path(URL)
class Father extends AbstractFamilyMember {
    public static final String URL = Grandfather.URL + "father/{name}";
}

@Path(URL)
class Son extends AbstractFamilyMember {
    public static final String URL = Father.URL + "son/{name}";
}
```

Do you have any suggestion to re-design this in order that doesn't involve overriding the children method?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: You havent declared the type for variable? In which case it won't compile :)

Comment: I have already tried it and it's "B". Thing is I'd like a stronger guarantee, such as documentation/specs/whatever, rather than relying on "it worked for now".

@MinhKieu it compiles and runs fine, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile...

Comment: Why do you need a guarantee of behavior for something you should never do? Simple **do not** give the same name twice, and behavior of duplicate name becomes irrelevant. Change to `@Path("path/{foo}/{bar}")`, or whatever names you want, and you can get both, or whichever one you want, though why you'd only ever want one of them is beyond me. Why require two values, if only one is needed?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA gives me a warning for the first `{variable}`: _Template variable is never used._

Comment: Is this Java? variable didn't have a type? Maybe Scala?

Comment: @gcandal What Minh Kieu is saying, is that parameter `variable` doesn't have a type, e.g. `String`. Method signature is incomplete and it will not compile. Should be `public void function(@PathParam("variable") String variable) {`

Comment: Guys, for god's sake, it's irrelevant whether it compiles or what the type of the variable is. See edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different names for your path parameters variable templates, then you can get the path parameters with [`UriInfo#getPathParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathParameters--) in the `AbstractFamilyMember#children()` method.

I would avoid the constants for the path. They make it hard to read. Keep it simple:

```java
public abstract class AbstractFamilyMember {

    @GET
    @Path("children")
    public Response children(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters = uriInfo.getPathParameters();
        String grandfatherName = pathParameters.getFirst("grandfatherName");
        String fatherName = pathParameters.getFirst("fatherName");
        String sonName = pathParameters.getFirst("sonName");

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```java
@Path("grandfather/{grandfatherName}")
public class Grandfather extends AbstractFamilyMember {
    ...
}
```

```java
@Path("grandfather/{grandfatherName}/father/{fatherName}")
public class Father extends AbstractFamilyMember {
    ...
}
```

```java
@Path("grandfather/{grandfatherName}/father/{fatherName}/son/{sonName}")
public class Son extends AbstractFamilyMember {
    ...
}
```

---

Depending on your requirements, you could bind the path parameters to fields:

```java
public abstract class AbstractFamilyMember {

    @PathParam("grandfatherName")
    private String grandfatherName;

    @PathParam("fatherName")
    private String fatherName;

    @PathParam("sonName")
    private String sonName;

    ...
}
```